# Button OnClick - How do I Add Function?

Tags: javascript, html, list, button, onclick

I've been handed a task for developing a small code in which I am expected to make an adjustable ordered list. It needs to have a placeholder, where the lists items will be typed and added, a on click button that will add that information to the ordered list and checkboxes next to every item, so they can be checked and the item's content must be strikethrough. This is what I have so far, can someone shine a light on this for me?

```js
function addToList() {
  let listItem = document.createElement("li");
  let textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
  let checkboxList = document.getElementById("checkboxList");
  // .innerHTML is what stays inside the <li>...</> on the HTML main code
  listItem.innerHTML = textInput.value;
  // textInput.value = "" clears the placeholder after the button is clicked
  textInput.value = "";
  checkboxList.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Write here" id="textInput" />
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Add to List" onclick="addToList()" />
<ol id="checkboxList"></ol>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Looks pretty good except you left out the checkbox.

Comment: If you put `[javascript] "to-do list"` into the Search box you'll find lots of similar questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

While your code works, using inline HTML event attributes like `onclick` is not advised [for a number of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991). Instead, use the modern API for setting up event handlers in JavaScript, rather than HTML: [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

The missing part (the checkboxes) are done in the same way that you dynamically created the new `li` elements.

See additional comments inline below:

```js
// Access the DOM element that needs an event handler and set the handler up
// in JavaScript with .addEventListener() instead of in the HTML with onXyz.
// Note that with `.addEventListener()` you only want to reference the function
// that will be the event handler, so you don't put () after it.
document.querySelector("#button1").addEventListener("click", addToList);

// Get your static element references just once, not every time the function runs
const textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
const checkboxList = document.getElementById("checkboxList");

// Functions that have been registered as event handlers will automatically
// be passed an argument that references the event object, so your event
// handling functions should set up a parameter to recieve that reference.
// The event reference can give you access to a variety of useful information
// like what key or mouse button was pressed or what the original element was
// that triggered the event (very handy when dealing with event bubbling).
function addToList(event) {
  const listItem = document.createElement("li");
  // Don't use .innerHTML if you can avoid it because it has performance and
  // security implications. Since the text you are working with here comes
  // from a textbox, there won't be any HTML that users enter anyway, so
  // it's better to use .textContent, which doesn't invoke the HTML parser
  // and doesn't open your code up to injection attacks.
  listItem.textContent = textInput.value;
  
  // Now, create a new checkbox to go with the list item
  const cb = document.createElement("input");
  
  // And configure all the aspects of the new checkbox
  cb.type = "checkbox"
  cb.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    listItem.classList.toggle("strikethrough"); // Toggle the CSS class that does the line through
  });

  listItem.appendChild(cb);   // Now add the new checkbox to the list item

  textInput.value = "";
  checkboxList.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

```css
.strikethrough { text-decoration:line-through; }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Write here" id="textInput">
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Add to List">
<ol id="checkboxList"></ol>
```